# *ignore* Convert the current time to a float value

Tags: android, time, floating-point

I tried converting the current time to a Float value, but the value that is returned isn't a Float

My code:

```
float currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getHours() + (Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getMinutes()/60);
```

I am not getting a Float value. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

This is the code that is working with the new not-deprecated methods:

```
float currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE)/60f);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code here

```
(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getMinutes()/60);
```

always return 0, since you're dividing integers.
Try

```
(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getMinutes()/60.0f);
```

or better, try to avoid deprecated methods lik getHours or getMinutes on a Date - get those info from the Calendar itself

Comment: I forgot the f, how sad is that :-P I'll use Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int hours = c.get(Calendar.HOUR); to get the time!

Answer (score 0):

```
float currentTime = ((float)Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getHours() + ((float)Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getMinutes())/60.0f);
```